# Consider whole result on order by

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a table with two columns OriginalName and SocialName
I am trying to order by these two using order by, but the problem is I want the two columns to be considered on the order by but my results are ordering by the first column and then by the other.

I have the table with the values like this

```
OriginalName                    SocialName

Beatriz N G LEMES               BEA LEMES
Carol Susan Jane Danvers        Carol Danvers
Cris colaboradora               Nome Social Cris 
Lucas André Márcio Rodrigues    NULL
Vinicius Cláudio Miguel Aragão  Alice Castro
Miguel Carlos Eduardo Farias    Alessandra Farias
Isis Aparecida Cristiane Assis  Isis  Assis
Danéria Targarião               Danny Targarião


select OriginalName,SocialName
order by case when Coalesce(SocialName,'') = ''  then   1 else  0 end , pfi.NomeSocial, pfi.Nome desc
```

After ordering the result comes like these

```
OriginalName                    SocialName

Miguel Carlos Eduardo Farias    Alessandra Farias
Vinicius Cláudio Miguel Aragão  Alice Castro
Beatriz N G LEMES               BEA LEMES
Carol Susan Jane Danvers        Carol Danvers
Danéria Targarião               Danny Targarião
Isis Aparecida Cristiane Assis  Isis  Assis
Cris colaboradora               Nome Social Cris 
Lucas André Márcio Rodrigues    NULL
```

as you can see it indeed order the table, but it's ordering the socialName and then ordering the original name for example, the OriginalName Cris colaboradora shouldn't be after the SocialName Danny Targarião, what i really wanted was to consider both columns as something like this:

```
OriginalName                    SocialName

Miguel Carlos Eduardo Farias    Alessandra Farias
Vinicius Cláudio Miguel Aragão  Alice Castro
Beatriz N G LEMES               BEA LEMES
Carol Susan Jane Danvers        Carol Danvers
Cris colaboradora               Nome Social Cris 
Danéria Targarião               Danny Targarião
Isis Aparecida Cristiane Assis  Isis  Assis
Lucas André Márcio Rodrigues    NULL
```

Comment: *the OriginalName Cris colaboradora shouldn't be after the SocialName Danny Targarião* Why?

Comment: because 'c' comes before 'd', i wanted to consider both columns on sorting

Comment: And 'n' comes after 'd' then why you want 'Nome Social Cris' before 'Danny Targarião'?

Comment: I see what you mean, but the order I need has to look to both columns, on that case, 'nome social cris' has the original name as 'cris colaboradora' (c)

Comment: i could just use union and order by, but then I wouldn't know what it original and what is social

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 case statements in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select * from tablename
order by 
  case when Coalesce(SocialName,'') = '' then 1 else  0 end,
  case
    when OriginalName < SocialName then OriginalName
    else SocialName
  end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43983cc1a77071bda5679ef2c4b7d328).
Results:

```
> OriginalName                     | SocialName       
> :------------------------------- | :----------------
> Miguel Carlos Eduardo Farias     | Alessandra Farias
> Vinicius Cláudio Miguel Aragão   | Alice Castro     
> Beatriz N G LEMES                | BEA LEMES        
> Carol Susan Jane Danvers         | Carol Danvers    
> Cris colaboradora                | Nome Social Cris 
> Danéria Targarião                | Danny Targarião 
> Isis Aparecida Cristiane Assis   | Isis  Assis      
> Lucas André Márcio Rodrigues     | null
```

Comment: sorry bout that , english is not my first language :/

Comment: No worries, mine neither.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this following script? this script is giving your expected output.

Check [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6df2bf8c26eb591ff270840b791e4901) Here.

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Combined,1,CHARINDEX('###',Combined,1)-1) OriginalName,
SUBSTRING(Combined,CHARINDEX('###',Combined,1)+3,LEN(Combined)) SocialName,
MIN(RN)
FROM 
(
    SELECT Combined,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OriginalName) RN
    FROM
    (
        SELECT OriginalName,OriginalName+'###'+SocialName Combined FROM your_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SocialName,OriginalName+'###'+SocialName FROM your_table 
    )A
)B
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Combined,1,CHARINDEX('###',Combined,1)-1),
SUBSTRING(Combined,CHARINDEX('###',Combined,1)+3,LEN(Combined))
ORDER BY 3
```